# Spring @ControllerAdvice doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-rest

I want to handle all exceptions thrown by any controller with the help of my GlobalExceptionHandler class. When I add following code to my controller, it works fine. But in this case I must add following code to all my controllers. But I don't want to repeat following code in each controller.

`@ExceptionHandler({ FiberValidationException.class })
    public String handleValidationException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) 
    {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }`

When I remove them and use my GlobalExceptionHandler class, it doesn't handle 
  exceptions.

What is the reason ? How I can fix it ?

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

@ExceptionHandler({ FiberValidationException.class })
public String handleValidationException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    LOG.error("FiberValidationException handler executed");
    return ex.getMessage();
}

@ExceptionHandler({ ChannelOverflowException.class })
public String handleOverflowException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    LOG.error("ChannelOverflowException handler executed");
    return ex.getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: You need to have the `GlobalExceptionHandler` declared as a bean somehow.

Comment: Can you paste bean code to here pls ?

Comment: No, it's general reference how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your global exception class with `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. e.g. `public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try and come back to you ;)

Comment: I checked out my log . And now it handle from GlobalHandlerClass  but  in my ajax error client side jqXHR.responseText;  is return like html  but I want  get my  error message

Comment: Do you mean that it started working (calling controller advice) if exception occurs?

Comment: yeah , now  it handle inside my GlobalHandlerClass

Comment: Ok great.. in that case it would be good if you accept this as answer to this question and raise another question for accessing error message in ajax request?

Comment: Let me know the thread where you are posting this ajax question.

Comment: alright I will paste link to here thank you for all ;)

Comment: no problem you made my day ;) And I have solved ajax problem add @ResponseBody to my exception methods ;)  Thnaks for all buddy ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might define the base package of the ControllerAdvice

Comment: I'am trying add  "<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.ControllerAdvice"/>" to my context:component-scan element. Maybe it will work :/

Comment: Is it your GlobalExceptionHandler bean created?

Comment: No I haven't create any bean for GlobalExceptionHandler in my xml file

Comment: Ok, but if your create a default constructor for it and log something on it or add a break point, the spring calls the constructor?

Comment: yeah I use log on it but it doesnt run :/ doesnt call

Comment: Do you have <mvc:annotation-driven /> tag in your application-context.xml?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146420/discussion-between-sandor-juhos-and-resul-rzyv-rm).

Comment: @ControllerAdvice(basePackages = { "com.datum.fnd.exception" })  I find soemthing like this

Answer (score 1):

in my case I was specified wrong exception for my function entry arguments, for example I passed EntityNotFoundException exception for MissingFormatArgumentException so my response to this exception was always 500 and it was never catched in my ControllerAdvice.